# Open a URL to start a process on server without UIWebView

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, url, uiwebview

I would like to open a URL that starts a conversion process on the websites servers without needing to load a UIWebView into memory. I tried this using `ASIHTTPRequest` but it didn't start the conversion process. Is there any API or any smart way to do this?

Heres the request:

```
ASIHTTPRequest *request = [[ASIHTTPRequest alloc] initWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://www.youtube-mp3.org/?c#v=%@",ID]]];
[request startAsynchronous];
```

That returns the html code as plain text but does not start the conversion process.

Comment: Can we see your ASIHTTPRequest code?

Answer (score 1):

ASIHTTPRequest is an excellent tool to communicate with a web server.  There is no requirement for a web view, since it's all communication code that can be run in a background thread.  You're on the right track.  You should figure out why the server process didn't start - are you sure that the url hit the correct method on the server?

Comment: I'm not familiar with that particular api - maybe you need to do a POST request? (I think ASIHTTP defaults to a get request)